# is there a way to loop over a variable i based off a list?

Tags: r, loops

I'm using the loop below to take a concatenated table and split it up equally and attach that part to the flowFrames within a flowSet object. This has worked great on my data so far as I've always had >50000 cells to look at. Now I have a dataset where there isn't a uniform number of cells and I can't afford to loose/drop those samples from the analysis.

```
cellnum<-50000 #change this to number of cells per file
start_cell<-1
end_cell<-cellnum
for (i in 1:length(d_flowSet)) {
  print(start_cell)
  print(end_cell)
  app.dataSmall<-app.data[start_cell:end_cell,]
  new_frame <- fr_append_cols(d_flowSet[[i]], app.dataSmall)
  filename_fcs <- filenames[i]
  Sys.sleep(1)
  write.FCS(new_frame, filename = filename_fcs,what="numeric", delimiter = "|", endian="big")
  end_cell<-end_cell+cellnum
  start_cell<-start_cell+cellnum
}
```

What I would like to do is change the loop so that the number of cells is taken from a list object called `eventCount`.

How do I do that? If you could explain the why that would be great too :)

Comment: Would this list hold both start and end cells?

Comment: Hi Nelson, No, the list is just the number of events/cells belonging to the individual flowFrame L